# how to combine two dataframes without a common key in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes `A` and `B`:

`A= 
    Date
    2016-01
    2016-02
    2016-03
    2016-04
    2016-05`

`B= 
    Titles
    Manager
    Direcotr
    Associates`

I'd like to have a dataframe of size 20x2 as follows:

`AB= 
    Date      Title
    2016-01    Manager
    2016-02    Manager
    2016-03    Manager
    ...
    2016-04    Associates
    2016-05    Associates`

This is what I tried:

```
columns = ['Date','Title']
b = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for i in A.Date:
    for j in B.Title:
        b.Date = i
        b.Title = j
```

But this does not work. Any hints would help a lot.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried pandas for the first time but maybe this is the answer you are looking for:

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': ['Date0', 'Date1', 'Date2', 'Date3']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Titles': ['Manager', 'Director', 'Associates']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2])

columns = columns = ['Date','Title']
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

prod = product(df1.values, df2.values)
for index, i in enumerate(prod):
    result.loc[index] = [i[0][0], i[1][0]]
```

Which gave me the output

```
    Date    Title
0   Date0   Manager
1   Date0   Director
2   Date0   Associates
3   Date1   Manager
4   Date1   Director
5   Date1   Associates
6   Date2   Manager
7   Date2   Director
8   Date2   Associates
9   Date3   Manager
10  Date3   Director
11  Date3   Associates
```

Comment: Thanks. Also wanted to add that since my A & B hada more columns I used `A['Date'].unique()` and `i[0][:]`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    import pandas as pd  
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': ['Date0', 'Date1', 'Date2', 'Date3']})

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Titles': ['Manager', 'Director', 'Associates']})

    result = pd.concat([df1, df2],axis = 1, join = 'outer', ignore_index=False, sort=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler version of Kiran's answer:

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': ['Date0', 'Date1', 'Date2', 'Date3']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Titles': ['Manager', 'Director', 'Associates']})
```

We just want a 1-d list of the values to pass to `product` whereas `.values` will get us a 2-d array

```
prod = product(df1['Dates'], df2['Titles'])
```

And we can construct the `DataFrame` directly from this

```
pd.DataFrame(list(prod),columns=['Date','Title'])
```

It is generally preferred (and much faster) to build the entire `DataFrame` from a list as opposed to row-by-row.

Also, there's of course no reason `A` and `B` need to be DataFrames. If they're lists or `Series` objects, then the code will be simpler yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
A['dummy'] = 1 
B['dummy'] = 1 
AB = A.merge(B, on='dummy')
AB = AB.drop('dummy', axis=1)
```